# Junit doReturn does not return correct response type

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am writing Junit for a method which has two methods, which has two different Rest calls but each rest call returns different response object.
When I try to mock this behavior using doReturn(responsetype1).when(restcall1),  first rest call gets success with return type as responsetype1 but for second method doReturn(responsetype2).when(restcall2) fails because doReturn(responsetype2) is not working instead it is still giving responsetype1. Someone please help with this

```
  public mainResponse add(HttpServletRequest request, String string1, HttpHeaders headers,
                                List<String> list) {
    
            boolean deleteStatus = method1(request, string1);
            if (!deleteStatus) {
                collectionResponse = method2(string1, colId, headers);
            }
        }
    
        public boolean method1(HttpServletRequest request, String string1) throws Exception {
            ResponseEntity<ResponseType1> responseType1 = restTemplate.exchange(url1, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers),
                    ResponseType1.class);
            //perfrom certain operation and return response
            return status;
        }
    
        ResponseType2 method2(String string1, String colId , HttpHeaders headers) {
            ResponseEntity<ResponseType2> response = restTemplate.exchange(url2, HttpMethod.POST,
                    new HttpEntity<>(body, headers), ResponseType2.class);
            return response.getBody();  //**this line is failing because ResponseType1 is being returned here**
        }
    
    My test class :
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
    doReturn(**ResponseType1**).when(restTemplate).exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                    ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<ResponseType1>>any());      
    doReturn(**ResponseType2**).when(restTemplate).exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                    ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<ResponseType2>>any());
    //other operation
    }
```

Comment: ArgumentMatchers is part of Junit5.

Comment: Use  ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.GET) or ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST) instead of
 ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class)

Comment: The same for ArgumentMatchers.eq(ResponseType2.class) instead of ArgumentMatchers.<Class<ResponseType2>>any()